# How can I find and fit enough string in a container in flutter

Tags: flutter, justify

I have a Container with a fixed size and I want to put as much as text possible inside of it, without needing to change container or text size (I receive a long text from an API and I want to make a substring(0,n), with n as big as possible to be able to be shown in my container)

I tried Justifying the text, but it doesn't help with the amount of text I should cut from my main string.

Comment: if the container has a fixed size just use TextOverflow.ellipsis

Comment: @AhmedElsarag Thats exactly what I wanted, thanks